# Firefox delay when scrolling from parent to child

Tags: firefox, scroll, delay

In firefox only, I noticed that when a parent and child both have overflow: scroll, there is a delay of a few seconds when scrolling from one to the other before the second element registers that it should continue the scroll.

You can see an example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/o9jnx0w5/9/

```
body {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}

.outer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      Inner Top
      <div class="bottom">
        Inner bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Place your cursor directly above the red div and scroll down. The page body will scroll first and reach the bottom of the page. Then there's a delay of a few seconds, after which the inner div will scroll until you see the text at the bottom of that div. Similar results when scrolling up.

Any known solutions?